# Include OneToMany relationship in query in peewee (Flask)

Tags: python, json, flask, peewee

I have two models Storage and Drawers

```
class Storage(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = CharField()
    description = CharField(null=True)

class Drawer(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = CharField()
    storage = ForeignKeyField(Storage, related_name="drawers")
```

at the moment I'm producing json from a select query

```
storages = Storage.select()
```

As a result I have got a json array,  which looks like this:

```
[{
   description: null,
   id: 1,
   name: "Storage"
},
{
   description: null,
   id: 2,
   name: "Storage 2"
}]
```

I know, that peewee allows to query for all drawers with `storage.drawer()`. But I'm struggling to include a json array to every storage which contains all drawers of that storage. I tried to use a join

```
storages = Storage.select(Storage, Drawer)
                  .join(Drawer)
                  .where(Drawer.storage == Storage.id)
                  .group_by(Storage.id)
```

But I just retrieve the second storage which does have drawers, but the array of drawers is not included. Is this even possible with joins? Or do I need to iterate over every storage retrieve the drawers and append them to the storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic O(n) query problem for ORMs. The documentation [goes into some detail on various ways to approach the problem](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#list-users-and-all-their-tweets).

For this case, you will probably want `prefetch()`. Instead of O(n) queries, it will execute O(k) queries, one for each table involved (so 2 in your case).

```
storages = Storage.select().order_by(Storage.name)
drawers = Drawer.select().order_by(Drawer.name)
query = prefetch(storages, drawers)
```

To serialize this, we'll iterate through the Storage objects returned by `prefetch`. The associated drawers will have been pre-populated using the Drawer.storage foreign key's `related_name` + '_prefetch' (`drawers_prefetch`):

```
accum = []
for storage in query:
    data = {'name': storage.name, 'description': storage.description}
    data['drawers'] = [{'name': drawer.name}
                       for drawer in storage.drawers_prefetch]
    accum.append(data)
```

To make this **even easier** you can use the `playhouse.shortcuts.model_to_dict` helper:

```
accum = []
for storage in query:
    accum.append(model_to_dict(storage, backrefs=True, recurse=True))
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, must have missed this particular part of the documentation. Was searching with the wrong buzzwords.